# Remote Desktop: how to switch between monitors?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

How can I switch between monitors on a remote connection?

Typical scenario: imagine yourself in a conference room with one single big display. Therefrom, you remote into your two-monitor rig, and monitor 1 is shown.

How can I switch to and from the second monitor?

Is there a keyboard shortcut to toggle which monitor is displayed? Thx, Keith :^D

EDIT 1: Using Windows Remote Desktop Connection
EDIT 2: 
 - W7 Enterprise, SP1
 - Shell Version 6.2.9200
 - Control Version 6.2.9200
 - Network Level Authentication Supported.
 - Remote Desktop Protocol 8.0 supported.

Comment: This is going to depend on what software you're using to remote - are you using RDP, Dameware, VNC, ...?

Comment: For RDP, this is version dependent. What is the version of `mstsc.exe`, and what version of Windows are you on?

Comment: Tried Windows + P ? (on the remote PC keyboard )